# Need a counterexample of limit of average integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ is integrable in $[0,1]$ and

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}f(x)dx=0$$

I feel that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ is incorrect, but I don’t know the example. I could only think about $1+\sin\frac{1}{x}$, but it seems that it’s not work.

In general, what do we know of $f$ as $x\to 0$ ?

Comment: What sort of integration theory are you using? Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: Consider the function $f$ that is $1$ when $x$ is rational, and $0$ when $x$ is irrational. Then the integral of $f$ on any interval is $0$, and $f$ does not have a (right) limit at $0$. The integral is 0 in the Lebesgue sense but is not defined in the Riemann sense.

Comment: For the Riemann case you can pick a function that is constant 0 everywhere and then throw in discontinuities at points of the form $1/n$. Then the limit as $x \to 0$ will not exist. The Riemann integral will exist because $f$ has only countably many discontinuities.

Comment: You want $h\to 0^+.$

Answer (score 1):

For $n>3,$ define the intervals $I_n =[1/n,1/n +1/n!].$ Then let $f(x) = 1$ on each $I_n,$ $f=0$ elsewhere. Note that $f$ is integrable, and does not have limit $0$ at $0.$

The idea here is that the $I_n$ are very small in length, with "lots" of space between them. So much space in fact that we expect

$$\tag 1 \frac{1}{h}\int_0^hf(x)\,dx \to 0\,\text{ as } h\to 0^+.$$

Let's try the sequence $h_n = 1/n +1/n!$ We get

$$\frac{1}{h_n}\int_0^{h_n}f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{1/n +1/n!}\int_0^{1/n +1/n!} f(x)\,dx$$ $$< \frac{1}{1/n}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} = n\left(\frac{1}{n!}+ \frac{1}{(n+1)!}+ \cdots \right).$$

Now the last expression $\to 0.$ That suggests that $(1)$ holds as desired. There are details remaining to verify, which I'll leave to you for now.

Answer (score 0):

For a continuous function, in the limit $h\to 0$, $$f(h)\approx f(0)$$and you can approximate the integral $$\int_0^h f(x)dx\approx f(0)h$$
Then, $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}f(x)dx\approx f(0)$$
So if your function is continuous then $f(0)=0$.